# Got a exception from play video based on local server! How to solve it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

program:

```
-(IBAction)playMV{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Pink_Try MV" ofType:@"mp4"]];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType=MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
    playercontroller = nil;

}
```

exception:

```
2015-12-07 16:49:35.448 iMusic[4999:308040] -[mainPageViewController play]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffaca4284a0
2015-12-07 16:49:35.454 iMusic[4999:308040] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[mainPageViewController play]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffaca4284a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecc1f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dec3deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecca56d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec17eea ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec17a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010bc4ae91 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010bdb64d8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010bdb67a4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010bdb58d4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010bcb8ed1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010bcb9c06 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010bc692fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010bc43abf _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebee011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebe3f3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebe33f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebe2e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f7fbad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010bc4930d UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  iMusic                              0x000000010b47773f main + 111
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011100c92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have some problem with ref counts, enable zombies and malloc debugging and run in the debugger to see if you can track down what is going on. Based on the code snip you posted, it is unclear what is going on.